# the result of .hasLabel("xxx") and .label() is not matching

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

The JanusGraph version is 0.5.3

storage.backend=hbase

I do this query，I get the correct label

```
gremlin> g.V().has("eventid","3bbe").label()
==>Company
```

but I do the follow query，I get result nothing

```
gremlin> g.V().has("eventid","3bbe").hasLabel("Company")
gremlin>
```

---

but use other eventid, i can get correct result

```
gremlin> g.V().has("eventid","4bbe").label()
==>Company
gremlin> g.V().has("eventid","4bbe").hasLabel("Company")
==>v[1714175422812422000]
```

Comment: Have you verified that the failing one does not have something like a space in the label such as "Company " ? - I would check the length of the label string returned by `label()`

Comment: These queries look fine, so i would also suggest taking a closer look at the contents of your vertex label.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kelvin and Binary suggestion stated in comments. You should check  the "Company" string once in "g.V().has("eventid","3bbe")" vertex properties. You can check the same using following query,

```
    g.V().has("eventid","3bbe").valueMap(true)
```

This will gives you "label" as property in the output value map.

Also, if then to you find that the String "Company" is same in both the query. Then there may be an issue in Indexing done on "eventid". (Assuming that some kind of index is created on this, as this can leads to this problem).

To solve this you can try reindexing. Steps are given as follows,

**For Reindex:**

```
    mgmt = graph.openManagement()
    i = mgmt.getGraphIndex('IndexName')
    mgmt.updateIndex(i, SchemaAction.REINDEX)
    mgmt.commit()
```

**For Enable the index:**

```
    ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'IndexName').status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call()
```

**NOTE:** if you get "false" in enabling the index, Try enabling it 2 3 times using the same command (ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'IndexName').status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call()). It would work eventually.